# Heroku: Using different version of imagemagick

Tags: php, heroku

I'm trying to get my Heroku instance to use a different (newer) version of ImageMagick, using this buildpack:
https://github.com/yespark/heroku-imagemagick-buildpack
I'm on the Heroku-20 stack

I see the version (7.1.0-20) is being installed, and I can confirm that it's there using `identify -version` - but when checking php -i, I see that PHP/Imagick is still using version 6.9.10-23:

```
imagick

imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.7.0
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
```

How can I ensure that imagick/PHP uses the correct version of ImageMagick?

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to Composer? Composer itself won't install any version of imagemagick, and your list of requirements doesn't even contain any information about imagemagick (which is not the same as imagick!)

Comment: You're right, sorry - so my actual issue might be this:
When uploading a HEIC image, that is supposed to be converted, using imagick (in PHP) i get the following error:
 `no decode delegate for this image format `HEIC' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361 `
But checking the ImageMagick version on the dyno (using the buildpack mentioned) I see that support for HEIC should be there:
`Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-20 Q16-HDRI x86_64 2022-01-22
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma png tiff webp xml zip zlib
Compiler: gcc (9.3)`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: How do you install imagick? As you can see, it has been compiled with ImageMagick in v6.9.10, so installing ImageMagick itself in any other version does not resolve your problem, as this does not recompile imagick

Comment: I'm installing ImageMagick, using this Buildpack: https://github.com/yespark/heroku-imagemagick-buildpack
As the first in my list of buildpacks.

Comment: And how did you install imagick? That is a different thing

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use this buildpack instead:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/daneren2005/heroku-buildpack-imagick
To make sure that I completely built ImageMagick and Imagick in the correct versions.
Please note that this buildpack should be added AFTER any PHP buildpack.